# React-native-camera appears as black screen

Tags: android, react-native, camera, android-camera, react-native-camera

I'm trying to implement an eKYC for my application, which included 3 camera screens (2 screens with back side camera, 1 with front side camera)

On some Android devices (Samsung Note 8, Xiaomi Redmi Pro 8, Vsmart Joy 3, ...), the third screen's camera (front side camera) is not working (black screen).

I've tried to read the errors from Android logcat and I receive this error:

```
2021-01-11 12:29:00.704 3973-13086/com.******.vn W/CameraBase: An error occurred while connecting to camera 1: Status(-8): '8: connectHelper:1648: Too many cameras already open, cannot open camera "1"'
```

Things I've tried: use `NavigationEvents` and `withNavigationFocus` to render the camera when current screen is focused

```
const [isFocus, setFocus] = useState<boolean>(false)
```

```
<NavigationEvents onWillFocus={onFocus} onWillBlur={onBlur}></NavigationEvents>
```

```
{isFocus && props.isFocused && (
    <RNCamera
      ref={refCamera}
      style={styles.preview}
      type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.front}
      captureAudio={false}
      onCameraReady={() => console.log('oncameraready')}
      onFacesDetected={onFaceDetected}>
      <View style={styles.progressBarContainer}>
        <Progress.Bar
          color={Colors.asEastOcean}
          progress={progress}
          width={200}
          style={styles.progressBar}
          borderColor={Colors.white}
          unfilledColor={Colors.white}
        />
      </View>
    </RNCamera>
  )}
```

But the camera on the third screen (front side camera) still not work. The other two work perfectly.
Is there any way to fix this, thank you very much in advance!

Note: If I change the order and render the third screen first, the front side camera is working normally.

Comment: Getting the same issue.. Have you found anything.

Comment: @VijaySinghChouhan Please check the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to fix the issues:
On the following file of react-native-camera:
`android/src/main/java/com/google/android/cameraview/Camera1.java`

I modified the `pausePreview` function as following:

```
    @Override
    public void pausePreview() {
        synchronized(this){
            mIsPreviewActive = false;
            mShowingPreview = false;

            if(mCamera != null){
                mCamera.stopPreview();
            }
            releaseCamera();
        }
    }
```

And if I have two consecutive screen that use the RNCamrera component, I used `navigation.replace()` instead of `navigation.navigate()`.

Answer (score 0):

android:hardwareAccelerated="false" in AndroidManifest.xml makes the camera no longer display. Check your AndroidManifest and set it back to true may help the camera work again.